# How does Index Hint and Query Execution Plan Work?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am running a series of test to ascertain how ignoring an index can affect the speed of my query. The following is the query string for the 1st test series:

```
SELECT P.pid, P.name, P.cty, P.fla, P.pos, P.lvl, P.akP * E.usD AS 'ask'
 FROM Pig P
 IGNORE INDEX FOR JOIN (id_fla) // index is on fla (MEDIUMINT) column
 INNER JOIN Eel E ON E.cur = P.cur
 WHERE P.status IN ('a', 'l') AND P.fla >107 AND P.cDate >CURDATE() AND P.pos <45
 HAVING ask BETWEEN '50' AND '500'
 ORDER BY fla DESC
 LIMIT 100;
```

In the 2nd test series, `IGNORE INDEX FOR`**JOIN** is replaced with `IGNORE INDEX FOR` **ORDER BY**. And in the 3rd test series, `IGNORE INDEX FOR ORDER BY` is replaced with `IGNORE INDEX FOR` **GROUP BY**.

Below is the test result and the corresponding Query Execution Plans.

**Test 1 (IGNORE INDEX FOR JOIN):**

```
Query Number (n): 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
Query Times (s):  90.6 0.13 27.2 21.4 0.11 0.10 29.8 27.8 0.17 6.56
Rows Examined (k):26   26   36   43   37   37   58   85   66   98
```

**Test 2 (IGNORE INDEX FOR ORDER BY):**

```
Query Number (n): 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
Query Times (s):  90.7 0.14 26.5 21.2 0.10 0.11 35.0 28.5 0.17 6.64
Rows Examined (k):26   26   36   43   37   37   58   85   66   98
```

**Test 3 (IGNORE INDEX FOR GROUP BY):**

```
Query Number (n): 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
Query Times (s):  263  10.1 10.1 9.95 9.94 10.1 10.0 9.95 9.96 10.1
Rows Examined (M):4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18 4.18
```

- Note 1: s - seconds, k - thousands, M - millions
- Note 2: `pos` is the only `WHERE` condition that varies between query
  1 to 10. The `WHERE` condition is exactly the same between the
  three tests for each query number.

**Test 1 (IGNORE INDEX FOR JOIN):**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: P
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5000014
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: E
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 3
          ref: BS.P.cur
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

**Test 2 (IGNORE INDEX FOR ORDER BY) and Test 3 (IGNORE INDEX FOR GROUP BY):**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: P
         type: range
possible_keys: id_flA
          key: id_flA
      key_len: 3
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4223660
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: E
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 3
          ref: BS.P.cur
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

Despite the fact that the query execution plan for Test 2 and Test 3 is the same and different from Test 1, the actual query speed and rows examined seems to group Test 1 and 2 together instead. So I have two questions that I need to ask:

1. How does Index Hint works in this case?
2. A table scan seems to be performed on Test 3 but index was shown to
   be used. Does MySQL follow through the query execution plan in the
   `EXPLAIN SELECT` statement?

Comment: An index hint can try to help the optimizer on what index might be best applied to your query when multiple are applied.  That said, and with the abbreviated query you've supplied, can you please supply the full query and qualify which table the "where" clause fields are associated with.  This information might better offer solutions to help you on what indexes may be best for performance... In addition, what are some primary purposes (conditions) your queries will be performed.

Comment: @DRapp: I have a simple index on `fla` column and a Primary Key on `pid`. The where clauses are all associated with table PIG. I have revised the query above. Can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
   WHERE 
          P.status IN ('a', 'l') 
      AND P.fla > 107 
      AND P.cDate > CURDATE() 
      AND P.pos < 45
   HAVING 
      ask BETWEEN '50' AND '500'
```

Your query itself looks fine (just clarifying format from your post).  However, if the only index you have is on fla, that's a problem.  Indexes should be based on what your querying criteria is based on... trying to focus more on common querying conditions that should derive the smallest granularity to help optimize..  I don't know which would be better... based on status, or entries based on cDate, then your where on fla and pos columns.   For example, if you have 4 million entries, and 500k are status "a", 400k as status "l", but only have 20k with a cDate > curdate(), THAT would be the starting point of your index... Index on the CDate... THEN add the next level of granularity.  If you have 15 different status codes, then how many of each status within that cDate segment?  But you know your data better than anyone out here at S/O, but I will make this suggestion for an index.

Index on (status, cdate, fla, pos ) and try that, then another index on (cdate, status, fla, pos ) and see which helps your performance.  How many "fla" values exist over 107 ?  If its s small amount, then maybe put THAT as your first index qualifier, but I doubt it as you were trying NOT to utilize that one.

Good luck, and hope this helps you think about your data a bit more.

Comment: I have tried using composite index, but it is not effective due to `fla` and `pos` being values that can cover all or none of the rows, `cData` and `status` cover most rows.